# Multicolumn and xintfor

Tags: tables, diagrams, multicolumn, xint

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Exchange, although I'm a frequent reader.

I tried to build a tabular that generates a sort of array, with indexes displayed above. This is the code:

```
$A = $
\raisebox{10pt}{
  \setcounter{N}{5}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
     \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\value{N}}}\do{\xintifForFirst{\tiny #1}{& \mc{\tiny #1}}}\\
    \hline
     $1$ & $3$ & $5$ & $7$ & $8$\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
```

where `\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}`.

[image]

I would like it to be exactly the way it is now, but without the first two vertical lines in the indexes row. If I use `\mc` in the first block of `\xintifForFirst` (as I did successfully for the second block) it doesn't compile and I can't understand why. The error I get is `! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit \@multispan`

Thanks in advance :-)

**Edit:** As suggested by Andrew I'm writing an example of the error I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcounter{N}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}

\newcommand{\myarray}[2]{
    \raisebox{8pt}{
        \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
            \setcounter{N}{#1}
            \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\value{N}}}\do{\xintifForFirst{\mc{    \tiny ##1}}{& \mc{\tiny ##1}}}\\
            \hline
            #2\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    $B = $\myarray{11}{$0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I edited the question

Comment: I suspect that the error has something to do with the "implementation features" box in section 15.17 (page 188) of the [xint](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) manual, but I didn't manage to solve the problem. I'm sure that @jfbu will be able to to fix this instantly.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Actually `\xintFor` isn't an expandable loop, and it makes some assignments at its start, and here an attempt is made to use `\multicolumn` which must be very first in a cell from expansion only. This being said, I will see if we can still use `\xintFor` here.

Comment: @Andrew +1! at last I have found someone who actually looks at the manual `:)`... but no, here the problem is not related to those hinted at in this "implementation features" box...

Comment: @jfbu Now you just need to find some one who reads the manual *and* interprets it correctly:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what packages you need to load to get your code to compile with `xint` - I tried `\usepackage{xint}` but this was not sufficient.

Would you consider a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) solution that produces

[image]

using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{array/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=5mm}}
\newcommand\Array[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]{\foreach \x [count=\c] in {#1} {
      \node[array, label=above:{\tiny \c}]at (\c/2,0){$\x$};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

$A = \Array{1,3,5,7,8}$

\end{document}
```

**EDIT I** - adding colour

Adding colour is fairly straightforward. If you want to have different colours in each cell then you can produce:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{array/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=5mm}}
\newcommand\Array[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{
    \foreach \x/\col [count=\c] in {#1} {
      \node[array, fill=\col!20, label=above:{\tiny \c}]at (\c/2,0){$\x$};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

$A = \Array{1/red,3/blue,5/white,7/green,8/white}$

\end{document}
```

If you want the same colour in each cell then, assuming that the cell entries are always *positive* you can use an easier input syntax by using negative numbers for colour to produce

[image]

using the marginally more complicated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{array/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=5mm}}
\newcommand\Array[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{
    \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#1} {
      \ifnum\x<0\relax
        \node[array, fill=blue!20, label=above:{\tiny \c}]at (\c/2,0){$\the\numexpr-\x\relax$};
      \else
        \node[array, label=above:{\tiny \c}]at (\c/2,0){$\x$};
      \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

$A = \Array{1,-3,5,-7,8}$

\end{document}
```

**EDIT II**

By the comments, the OP wants to allow both shading and being able to typeset the entries in bold. Also, `0` is a valid entry so, unlike in Edit I, it is not enough to check the sign of an entry to determine shadability or boldness.

The new macro below accepts a comma separated list where the entries are (assumed to be) numbers that are optionally decorated with `b`, for bold, and `s`, for shade. So, for example, the code

```
$A=\Array{s0, s0, sb1, s0, sb1, s0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}$
```

will produce

[image]

By default, the squares are `5mm` wide but this can be changed using an optional argument, so that

```
$A = \Array[8]{1,sb30,0b,s5,b7,8}$
```

produces "squares" that are `8mm` wide:

[image]

To recognise the `b` and `s` "flags" I had to use some [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) trickery. There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but there is an extra complication in that [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) does not play well with [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3). The `s` and `b` flags can appear anywhere to the extent that `s1b2` would put `12` in bold in a shaded box.

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\tikzset{array/.style={rectangle, draw}}

\NewDocumentCommand\nodetext{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_text_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN {noN}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_in:nnTF {onTF}
\NewDocumentCommand\SetUpNode{m}{
  \tl_gset:No \g_text_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:noN {[bs]*} {} \g_text_tl
  \str_if_in:onTF {#1} {b}
    {\RenewDocumentCommand\nodetext{}{$\mathbf{\tl_use:N \g_text_tl}$} }
    {\RenewDocumentCommand\nodetext{}{$\tl_use:N \g_text_tl$} }
  \str_if_in:onTF {#1} {s} { \tikzset{array/.append~style={fill=blue!20}} }{}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\Array[2][5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
    \tikzset{array/.append style={minimum width=#1mm}}
    \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#2} {
      \SetUpNode{\x}
      \node[array, label=above:{\tiny\c}]at(#1*\c/10,0){\nodetext};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  $A=\Array{s0, s0, sb1, s0, sb1, s0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}$

  \bigskip

  $A = \Array[8]{1,sb30,0b,s5,b7,8}$

\end{document}
```

The code currently supports only one colour for shading but this would be easy enough to change by adding extra letters and then adding extra lines of the form:

```
\str_if_in:onTF {#1} {s} 
  { \tikzset{array/.append~style={fill=blue!20}} }{}
```

[Note that I could use `\str_if_in:onT` here, but I didn't want to generate another variant...]

Comment: It's `\usepackage{xinttools}`...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this implementation doesn't allow change of cell color by the user of the macro... Your solution is very elegant and I like it, but my version is more appropriate for my needs, except for the fact that it doesn't compile :-(

Comment: @GemmaMartini Colour is not mentioned in the OP but it is easy enough to incorporate. How do  you want the cell colours to change?

Comment: I would like to change the colour of some cells, when I pass them to the macro... Using my code I could have used `$B = $\myarray{11}{\cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$\mathbf{1}$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$\mathbf{1}$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$}`

Comment: I did, although my reputation doesn't allow my upvote to be visible.

Comment: Anyway, I've three more questions (that also prove the thesis that my implementation was easier to use):
(1) If I use -0 it doesn't work, so the entries have to be strictly positive, not only non negative
(2) I can't make some cells both highlighted and bold, without changing significantly the macro, can I?
(3) The minimum width can't be increased, because the layout of the thing explodes.
I like your solution very much, but I'm not able to customize it :-(

Comment: @Andrew, you're right. When I posted the question I thought that the answer would have been a fix of my code, so the "signature" of the macro wouldn't have changed.
The most complex call of that macro in my source code is `$B = $\myarray{11}{\cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$\mathbf{1}$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$\mathbf{1}$ & \cellcolor{\mycolor}$0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$}`... I don't know if there's anything that can be done to have the output I need, sorry for all the trouble :-(

Comment: @GemmaMartini HI! I finally got back to this. See my edit.

Comment: It's lovely! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I see @Andrew has provided answer with added possibilities, but only to answer the original question:

`\xintFor` proceeds non expandably *at the start of its execution*. Thus it is impossible to use it to insert a `\multicolumn`, but it would work with a `&\multicolumn`.

So to fix the OP, we only have to treat directly the first multcolumn, then for the subsequent ones we can use the `\xintFor` loop.

Side note: `\xintFor` proceeds expandably *at its end*, which allows things like using it to insert a `\\` and then execute after the xintFor loop a `\hline`. On the other hand this feature has some constraints which are the ones commented in the manual. These limitations are of no direct relevance to the matter here, which has to do with the behaviour at *start*  of loop.

Here is OP minimally modified to let it work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

% \newcounter{N} % not needed
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}

\newcommand{\myarray}[2]{
    \raisebox{8pt}{
        \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
            \mc{\tiny 1}%
            \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{2}{#1}}% we assume always #1 > 1
            \do {&\mc{\tiny ##1}}\\
            \hline
            #2\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    $B = $\myarray{11}{$0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It looks nicer with

```
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
```

i.e. centered tiny numbers:

[image]

Comment: @GemmaMartini I should add this kind of issue to the xinttools doc...

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I need, since I know how it works and I can modify it :-)

Comment: @GemmaMartini As jfbu's answer best fits yours needs you should award the green tick.

Comment: The documentation of `\xintFor` definitely should mention that it can't inject `\multicolumn` (because `\xintFor` makes non-expandable things at the start of each iteration) but works fine with `&\multicolumn` (because here nothing is injected in-between the `&` and the `\multicolumn` and non-expandability before the `&` is ok). As my punishment for this lack of information in `xint.pdf` I suggest you do maintain the green tick awared to @Andrew `:)`

Comment: Ok, then. Green tick to @Andrew, with extra thanks to jfbu for the final solution.
Thank you both very much, my first experience on stack exchange was awesome! I hope I will be able to answer and not only ask :-)